# C# Excel Textbox - How to reference text for a textbox from a cell

Tags: c#, excel, textbox

I'm trying to pass the value of a cell to the textbox using `c#` but the text box does not READ the value in the cell...instead it display's the cell address:

Here is the code snippet:

```
Excel.Shape textBox1 = wsDashBoard.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 53,72,69,37);
textBox1.TextFrame.Characters(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing).Text = "=Dashboard!$A$3";
```

Actual result: Textbox created with `=Dashboard!$A$3` as the text

Expected result: text in the `textbox1` should read the value in the cell `A3`

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Please be more precise about how you create the excel object. For now I do not know how I could help.

Comment: `textBox1.TextFrame.Characters(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing).Text = wsDashBoard.Range("A3").Value;` assuming `wsDashBoard` is same as `Dashboard` that you have used in formula `=Dashboard!$A$3`

Comment: Yes shahkalpesh...you are correct..

Comment: Mark here is the patch where i create chart objects:
Excel.ChartObjects xlDonCharts1= (Excel.ChartObjects)wsDashBoard.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject dbDonChart1=(Excel.ChartObject)xlDonCharts1.Add(2, 8, 170, 170);
Excel.Chart chartDon1 = dbDonChart1.Chart; chartDon1.SetSourceData(donData1);
chartDon1.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlDoughnut;
Excel.Shape textBox1 = wsDashBoard.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 53,72,69,37);
textBox1.TextFrame.Characters(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing).Text = "=Dashboard!$A$3"

Comment: Solved: Here is the snippet for others help>>>
Excel.Range donData1 = wsDashBoard.get_Range("C6", "C9"); 
Excel.Range donLab1 = wsDashBoard.get_Range("C3"); textBox1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = donLab1.Value.ToString("0%");

i created a range and then passed it as the text for the textbox